# Meteor: Workaround for having websockets blocked in port 80?

Tags: meteor, websocket, ddp

I am having problems with a Meteor app. Some smartphones are not receiving data from subscriptions when they are connected via 3G/4G but they work properly when connecting via Wi-Fi. I think it is because Vodafone (a mobile network operator) is blocking websocket connections to port 80.

Is it possible to change the DDP port? Does anyone have a workaround to make it work?

I have tried changing the environment variable `"DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL": "ddp+sockjs://xxxxxx.com:443/sockjs"` but it breaks the app for all devices and throws the following error:

```
GET http://0.0.1.187/sockjs/info?cb=23ctb533n5 net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Thank you very much for your help and time!

Comment: 443 is for https. Maybe you should try another port, like 81.

Comment: I have tried other ports, and 81 now. It does not work.

Comment: @JorgeSanz Use https. Vodafone cant block it when it cant see it

Comment: so you need an https proxy, meteor cant to it natively, to my knowledge. But there are several proxy available out there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work out-of-the-box in Meteor, since the engine supposedly falls back to a backup technology (AJAX+JSON) if WebSockets fail. However, I had the same issue and still couldn't figure out why this wasn't automagic.

You can however force this behavior with

```
DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=1
```

From here: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Websockets

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Fernando. I can’t check if your answer solves the problem.
When I posted this question, I wasn’t able to make the app work.